# Jquery loop through TRs and get child selected option

Tags: jquery

So I need to loop through a dynamic number of table rows. In each row are 3 cells. In cell 2 and 3, I have a select box, which I need to retrieve the value from.

I've tried the following different combinations of code, but all return `undefined`:

```
$('tbody#mapping_table > tr').each(function(i, obj){

// These are alternatives I've tried within the loop:

     console.log($(obj).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select > option:selected').val());

// ---- OR ----

     console.log($(obj).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('option:selected').val());

// ---- OR ----

     console.log($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('option:selected').val()); 

// ---- OR ----

     console.log($(this).children('td:nth-child(2) > select > option:selected').val());

// ---- OR ----

     console.log($('td:nth-child(2) > select > option:selected', $(this)).val());

});
```

All alternatives return `undefined`.
This would be a sample of my html:

```
<tbody id="mapping_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Some Value 1</td>
        <td>
            <select name="xml_field[some_value_1]">
                 <option value="1">Select value 1</option>
                 <option value="2">Select value 2</option> 
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="join_field[some_value_1]">
                <option value="1">Join select value 1</option>
                <option value="2">Join select value 2</option> 
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I just need to loop through each `tr` and retrieve the 2 selected values from each. Any idea's on what I should try next?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `tr` you can find `select`s inside second and third `td` and take selected values of this `select`s in this way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L986hsks/1/).

```
$('tbody#mapping_table > tr').each(function()
{
    var firstValue = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2) select').val();
    var secondValue = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3) select').val();
});
```

About your tries:

```
$(obj).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('select > option:selected').val();
```

is incorrect because of `children('select > option:selected')`: `.children()` goes only one level down in DOM.

```
$(obj).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('option:selected').val();
```

has the same problem.

```
$(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').children('option:selected').val();
```

`this` equals `obj` inside `.each()`, so it is the same as second try.

```
$(this).children('td:nth-child(2) > select > option:selected').val();
```

has the same problem with `children`.

```
$('td:nth-child(2) > select > option:selected', $(this)).val();
```

should actually work correctly.

Comment: Awesome, a lot more elegant that a 'fix' I had worked out, and exactly what I wanted (I'll have to remember to use `find` instead of `children` for this type of problem in future). Thanks.

Comment: @PhilCross you're welcome. Take a look at Edit, if you want to know why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Just tried the last one and it worked, maybe I typed it correctly on SO but not in my actual code! Either way, I prefer your version as it's less code to write! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('tbody#mapping_table > tr').each(function (i, obj) {
        console.log($(obj).children('td:nth-child(2)').find('select option:selected').val());
    });
});
```

This works as find can traverse all the way down as opposed to children only going 1 level below http://api.jquery.com/children/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ytft9aLd/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've tested both answers and both worked as I wanted, but Regents was more towards what I was trying originally, but +1 for the answer and explaination :) Thanks